# Problem rewriting vb6 to c#

Tags: c#, com, vbscript

I have this code I'm trying to rewrite to c# from a vbs script.

VB has an array function.

So the VB line of code looks like this (In reality it is an LDAP call):

> dGrp.Put "ShowInAddressBook",
>   Array("val", "val")

I would think the c# equiv would be:

```
dGrp.GetType().InvokeMember("Put",
InvokeMemberFlags,
null, dGrp, new object[] { "ShowInAddressBook", addressBookvalues.Split(',') });
```

But this doesn't work.

I can't call the PUT method multiple times either, because it overwrites previous values. It's expecting all the values.

The script works, but the c# produces this:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.
>   COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified
>   error (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004005  (E_FAIL))

Any help would be good, thanks!

EDIT: Sorry for not explicitly mentioning the solution needs to remain COM based. So using managed code alternatives is not an option (in this case).

Binding flags are:

```
private static BindingFlags setCOMBindings()
        {
            return BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                   BindingFlags.Public |
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                   BindingFlags.Instance |
                   BindingFlags.InvokeMethod;
        }
```

Comment: If its LDAP you're using, why don't you have a look at the System.DirectoryServices namespace? I'm assuming you're making changes to an AD entry.

Comment: What are you passing in as your BindingFlags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was better as a comment but I don't have enough reputation, so here it goes:

I'm not familiar with LDAP, therefore I don't know the objects you're talking about, but wouldn't be possible that the problem is the way you're marshaling the array of values?

If the method is expecting a VARIANT array, maybe the array of address book values should be an array of object instead of an array of strings.

Maybe it would be important if someone could get the signature, in COM way, of this Put method.

Comment: I tried to pass in an object[] but that didn't work either. At this stage, I would love to see some documentation too of this put method.

Comment: What is the type of your dGrp variable?

Comment: I have found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.71).aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforarraysanchor4) that shows how arrays are marshaled between managed and unmanaged code. If the method is expecting an array of variants, it states that you should use System.Array (with a pointer to _Array or as, what i think is the right one, as SAFEARRAY(VARIANTS)).

Comment: I read the article, but can't figure out how to practically use that information, can someone give a code sample?

Comment: Ok figured it out, thanks to your help! Been busy on this problem for about 12 hours now. Solution is to create a private variable and include marshall as attributes to it.    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
        private static object[] obj;

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
...


    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<your_dn_here>");
    object[] entries = addressBookValues.Split(',');
    entry.Properties["ShowInAddressBook"].AddRange(entries);

    try 
    { 
    entry.CommitChanges(); 
    Console.WriteLine("Success!!");
     }
     catch(Exception e) 
    {
     Console.WriteLine(e);
     }
```

Comment: thanks for this, however I need to do this using a COM approach. In this case - reason = long story.

Comment: @JL - Would you be able to make a .Net assembly COM visible and then use that? I work in Visual Fox Pro a lot of the time, and have written COM stuff in C# because its easier, and when the app finally gets upgraded, the COM components are already migrated.